# Running Cypress through Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cypress

I am trying to run Cypress from a NodeJS Firebase function using the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api). The execution goes fine on my local machine but throws an error when running deployed to Firebase. Puppeteer works fine in the same context, but I would prefer to use Cypress if possible.

The Cypress command is:

```
    const cypress = require('cypress');

    return cypress
        .run({
            spec: 'cypress/integration/FirebaseTest.spec.js',
            configFile: 'cypress/config/cypress.json',
            // headless: false,
            // headed: false,
            env: {
                products_url: '/products',
            },
        });
```

The error I get is:

```
Unhandled error { Error: No version of Cypress is installed in: /root/.cache/Cypress/7.2.0/Cypress

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

----------

Cypress executable not found at: /root/.cache/Cypress/7.2.0/Cypress/Cypress

----------

Platform: linux (Ubuntu - 18.04)
Cypress Version: 7.2.0
...
...
```

package.json snippet

```
"dependencies": {
        "cypress": "^7.2.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.5.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
        "puppeteer": "^9.1.1",
}
```

Comment: Did you install the module? Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes, it's installed as a dependency. That's how it actually knows it's version 7.2.0.

Comment: From the error you're receiving it is clear that something is wrong with the dependency installation. I'd revise the steps you follow for the function deployment and see if it aligns with what is stated in the documentation for [Specifying Dependencies in Node.JS](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#configuring_deployment_dependencies)

Comment: We've been working with Firebase functions in production for a couple of years now, so the dependencies are probably ok. Running Cypress from the same project has no issues when run on a local machine, it's once deployed to firebase that it has this problem.

Comment: Other iterations of people trying to use Cypress in Firebase Cloud Functions seem to be using [cypress-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase). Would this fit your needs/work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Roger, I had a look at the Github repo of the project, but it seems this is a lib to test the frontend which is actually working fine for me. My issue is regarding running the test from within a Firebase function i.e. with Cypress Module API. Can you link some working examples of the test being run **from** a deployed Firebase function?

Comment: From [this thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2610) I’ve found some commands that can be useful to you. Can you try to run `npm install cypress --save-dev` and  `node_modules/.bin/cypress install`. When the installation is completed you run `node_modules/.bin/cypress open` and it should solve your issue. Could you please confirm whether this helps you or not?